# Can one connect an USB-hub to the ethernet port?

Tags: linux, usb, ethernet

My system:
2x USB 2.0
1x 1000MBit Ethernet
Wifi
OS: Linux

I want to connect an usb-hub, but plugging it into the usb 2.0 is super slow. Is there a possibility to connect the usb-hub to the ethernet port? I am anyway only using Wifi for Internet. I don't care which Linux distribution to use as long as I can write images to sd-cards with it.

Google-"Research" only gives me "usb -> to -> ethernet" adapters but no usb-hubs pluggable into ethernet.

Thank you very much for any help :-)

Comment: How do you expect it behaves after connecting it? As network hub or as USB hub?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Expected to act as USB hub. I thought it to be about programming, since I expected an answer like: buy an adapter and tweak Linux like .... . Maybe also off topic, sorry! I'll read through your links and will hopefully improve :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is not possible because of the structure of USB protocol. USB requires a host device (normally the pc) and in an ethernet driver can *never* be implemented USB host functionality with reasonable effort. A USB hub is a device

*ethernet-over-USB* uses the USB CDC class and *emulates* an ethernet port (eth0,...) to the os. From the viewpoint of USB protocol in this case the structure is clear. pc is USB host *Ethernet-over-USB* adapter is USB device.

An ethernet port does not even know what an USB device is (protocol structure) and it does not even have the physical interface...

Comment: Too sad for my case, but thank you for explaining! :)